# Reusing a Button in Java Makes Nothing Display

Tags: java

I am really new to GUI programming in Java so please forgive me if this code is really basic. In short, I want to have 2 panels that are the same design. After I press the "A" button on the panel 1, I want to make panel 2 appear with the same design. Making the GUI efficient or pretty doesn't currently matter to me. I just want it to work. I have parts of the code listed below.

```
  JButton buttonA = new JButton("a");
  JButton buttonB = new JButton("b");
  JButton buttonC = new JButton("c");
  JButton buttonD = new JButton("d");

  JPanel pan1 = new JPanel(); 
  JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();

    setTitle ("Test");
    setSize (640, 640);

    setResizable(false);

    GridLayout grid1 = new GridLayout();
    setLayout (grid1);

    FlowLayout flow1 = new FlowLayout();

    pan1.setLayout (flow1);

    pan1.add(buttonA);
    pan1.add(buttonB);
    pan1.add(buttonC);
    pan1.add(buttonD);

    buttonA.addActionListener(this); 
    buttonB.addActionListener(this); 
    buttonC.addActionListener(this); 
    buttonD.addActionListener(this); 

    FlowLayout flow2 = new FlowLayout();
    pan2.setLayout (flow2); 
    pan2.add(buttonA);
    pan2.add(buttonB);
    pan2.add(buttonC);
    pan2.add(buttonD);

    add(pan1);
    add(pan2);

    pan1.setVisible(true); 
    pan2.setVisible(false);
    setVisible(true); 

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (command.equals("a")){//i want to show the panel 2 after button a is pressed
      System.out.println("HelloA");
      pan1.setVisible(false); 
      pan2.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Currently, it just shows nothing in the window. Any help guys?

Comment: You can't add the same button to two different panels. Or rather, you can, but then it ill be removed from the first one.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is, you can't.

Long answer is, a component can only reside on a single parent.  Adding a component to a second container will automatically remove it from the first container before its added to the new one.

Instead, you will need to create individual buttons for both containers.

Also, understand that `BorderLayout` can't support what you're trying to do, it will only manage one component at a time (in each of the 5 available positions)

A better solution would be to make use of the [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which is designed to facilitate the action you are trying to achieve

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer. My current project is a quiz about answering multiple choice. I have seen the website that you have sent me. However, on top of the fact that I do not understand some of the code that is on he website, the Card Layout seems confusing. If I Have 10 questions (each with 4 answers, do I need to 40 buttons?) May I see an example of what some of that code might look like?

Comment: Honestly, you need one custom panel and 10 buttons, which can be configured with the information you need, then you can either create 4 instances of the panel and swap them, or simply change the configuration of the single panel. *"I do not understand some of the code that is on he website"* - I would strongly suggest that you take the time to learn and understand it, as nothing we do will be anything less then what's on the offical tutorial site provides

Comment: Note, if you have 10 different questions, you only need one `QuestionPanel` with a `setQuestion(..)` method.